# Determining the Parent Folder of a given Path in C#

Tags: c#, file, directory

```
pages/parentdirectory/directory
```

how can I extract the parent directory in C# ?

Comment: Look into `Directory` class

Comment: Something more specific would be nice

Comment: Have you done any research? Are familiar with any class of `System.IO` namespace?

Comment: of course, and i haven't found anything, I believe a short answer would be useful for many people. i know the classes FILE, DIRECTORY and PATH.

Comment: @timomüller you haven't found anything? You must be kidding... Please read what/how to ask here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Directory.GetParent. .. which returns a DirectoryInfo and you can get the Name or FullName

```
var info = Directory.GetParent(@"directory_path");
var name = info.Name; //this will give parentdirectory
var fullName = info.FullName; //this will give pages/parentdirectory
```